# Menu bar leaves side space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a menu bar. The container is called: #menu and has the following CSS: `border: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;`

The problem is that when I set the width of the menubars to 12.5%, they leave space on the side. Sorry but I can't show the real contents so I'm giving this image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3z86dugdw5q9ezd/test.png . The CSS for the menu_bars is: `width: 12.5%;
    float: left;
    padding: 25px 18px 25px 18px;
    background: rgba(237, 157, 28, 0.992157);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 20px;`

Comment: It is hard to diagnose your actual problem if you do not try replicating your problem with code, preferably on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eWNSz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare this for the `.menu_bar_item`:

```
.menu_bar_item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* more styles */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/eWNSz/1/

The `box-sizing: border-box` property prevents padding from adding onto the width (that is the default behavior, anyway). With this property declared, you will need to look into adjusting your `height` property, too.

Comment: Increase the height, as simple as that. I supposed with a navigation like that, you would want to restrict the height, afterall.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the left padding to 20px.